# Wordpress register_activation_hook not working in my class

Tags: wordpress

My folder:

```
my-plugin/
---inc/
------class-my-plugin.php
---my-plugin.php
```

In file my-plugin.php:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/inc/class-my-plugin.php' );
```

In file class-my-plugin.php:

```
class MyPlugin {

   public static function pluginActivate() {
      add_option( '__MY_PLUGIN_ACTIVE__' , true );
   }

   public static function pluginDeactivate() {
      update_option( '__MY_PLUGIN_ACTIVE__' , false );
   }

}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'MyPlugin', 'pluginActivate' ) );

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'MyPlugin', 'pluginDeactivate' ) );
```

But when i actvate or deactivate, it not working. Somebody can help me?

Comment: You should be using [plugins_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) instead of your `require_once`.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your use of [`add_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option):

> A safe way of adding a named option/value pair to the options database table. **It does nothing if the option already exists**.

Try using `update_option()` for both the activate and deactivate to properly affect the option value. If  this doesn't work, add some `error_log()` writes to your actions to make sure they are firing.